# Optimizing Image Rotation in Java Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When creating lots of objects what takes less time and less resources?

```
ctx.save();
ctx.restore();
```

or just rotating and translating it back? or are they the same?

```
ctx.translate(-x,-y);
ctx.rotate(-d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious too, so I created a benchmark: https://jsperf.com/restore-vs-translate/1

On both chrome and firefox it seems that translating and rotating back are much faster.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! I didn't know about that site. Do you know why my question got marked down?